# Chinese and Japanese characters not working with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a table named `CHINESE` which has only one column `NAME`.
The output of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%'` is:

```
+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                                  |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                                   |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                                   |
| character_set_database   | latin1                                                 |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                                 |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                                   |
| character_set_server     | latin1                                                 |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                                   |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/local/mysql-5.1.73-osx10.6-x86_64/share/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

When I run this query: `INSERT INTO CHINESE VALUES ('你好')`, the values get inserted.
But, when I try to execute this query: `SELECT * FROM CHINESE`, the result is:

```
+------+
| NAME |
+------+
| ??   |
+------+
```

The result of `SELECT HEX(NAME) FROM CHINESE` is:

```
+-----------+
| HEX(NAME) |
+-----------+
| 3F3F      |
+-----------+
```

Where am I making mistake?

Comment: You might have data in your database that's actually UTF-8 but the server is incorrectly assuming it's Latin1. Does setting your connection to Latin1 make it appear correctly? Since Latin1 is an 8-bit character set, it can have UTF-8 data stored in it, though it will look mangled when you try and display it as actual Latin1 characters.

Comment: When I insert values in database, the actual values aren't persisted, instead, '?' character is persisted. When I switch to 'latin1', and execute the select statement, the result is still the same.

Comment: But, when I insert values while in 'latin1', the output is fine.

Comment: You should try switching the server, connection, everything to `utf8`, make a new database and test table, insert there, and see if it works. I think you've got UTF-8 data but the server's doing conversion as if it was Latin1.

Answer (score 1):

If mysql>=5.5.3, use utf8mb4 .

1. Alter origin table

```
ALTER TABLE $tablename
  CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 
  COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci
```

2. Create new table

```
CREATE TABLE $tablename (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

3. Modify Column

```
ALTER TABLE $tablename
    MODIFY $col1
    VARCHAR(191)
    CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

refer:  [Mysql DOC: Column Character Set Conversion](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-conversion.html)

Answer (score -2):

Try the following to change the character set: `SET NAMES 'big5';`

Comment: Why can't I do it with 'utf8'?

Comment: When I use SET NAMES 'latin1', it works. But I want to use 'utf8' here.

Comment: UTF-8 is suitable for texts that are mostly Latin alphabet letters.

Comment: I also want it to work with latin alphabets. Will 'big5' work well with them?

Comment: I believe it is only for Asian alphabets.  Your post didn't specify that you didn't want Asian only, so that is why I provided the answer that I did.